# Connecting a wire to both terminals of battery

Tags: batteries, short-circuit

If I connect a wire to both ends of a battery (say 9 V) the battery gets very hot (dangerous).

How can I “force” the wire to heat up but not the battery? What component do I need to put between the wire and battery to achieve this?

Comment: There is no such component; the battery *will* heat up when shorted.

Comment: Hearth, thanks. Q. Does not the resistance of the wire determine whether the battery heats up? If I had a very high resistant wire would the battery actual likely stay cool?

Comment: Yes, a high resistance wire would lead to lower current, meaning less heating in both the battery and the wire.

Comment: So how could I create a heating element then (I.e. like a kettle)? In my head I just wanted to connect a wire to a battery and heat it up. I know however that the battery will heat up so was wondering how to keep the power source cool while heating the element.

Comment: In a kettle, the heater itself is that resistor.

Comment: Careful design and the use of a more appropriate battery. Making a battery-powered kettle is an exercise in futility though; there's a reason you don't see a lot of battery-powered heating elements outside of novelty devices and cheap junk that doesn't work. A heating element of sufficient power for cooking or heating a room is going to require more energy than a battery of practical size can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nichrome wire makes a good heating element - however you'll want more length and less diameter (gauge) to increase the resistance of the heating wire to a value greater than that of the equivalent series resistance (ESR) of the battery.

9V batteries have a fairly high ESR according to this website, and the other datasheet:

http://www.muzique.com/lab/batteryz.htm

https://docs.rs-online.com/957a/A700000007080520.pdf

the best being around 4 ohms and the worst new batteries at 26 ohms, raising to 200 ohms near depletion. The amount of power wasted in the battery will be \$P=I^2R\$, P is the power in watts which is the rate heat will be added. Since The current \$I\$ is the same in the battery as it is in the heating wire, your only option is to reduce \$I\$ and bias the \$R\$ in the circuit towards the heating wire.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Bryan, this makes sense to me now - the internal resistance of the battery….